# sentinels value in arrays using c

Tags: c, arrays

Global warming. As part of a global warming analysis, a research facility tracks outdoor temperatures at the North Pole once a day, at noon, for a year. At the end of each month, these temperatures are entered in to the computer and processed. The operator will enter 28, 29, 30, or 31 data items, depending on the month. You may use -500 as a sentinel value after the last temperature, since that is lower than absolute 0. Your main program should call the read_temps(), hot_days(), and print)temps() functions described here:

my question is that sentinel values are only used in while loops right or is there a way to use it in for loop. As you can see am trying to put the temperatures in an monthly array but i have to keep in consideration how many days are in this month.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
        int temp;
        int x;

        int dailyTempsAry[31];

        printf("Please enter today's temperature: \n");
        scanf("%d",&temp);

        while (temp != -500) {
                for (x = 0 ; x<31; ++x) {
                        dailyTempsAry[x] = temp;

                        printf("Please enter today's temperature:\n ");
                        scanf("%d",&temp);
                }
        }

        for (x = 0 ; x<31; ++x) {
                printf("%d\n",dailyTempsAry[x]);
        }

        getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to read data for fixed number of days only like 31, 30, 29, or 28 days then why need to use sentinel value.

Answer (score 3):

You could use them in for loops equally well, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; arr[i] != sentinel; ++i) {

}
```

Comment: but when i do ur for loop it just puts the sentinel in the array

Answer (score 2):

For loops are just while loops with nicer formatting.

Consider the following:

```
for (int i=0; i <= 10; ++i)
{
    // do something
}
```

Compared to this:

```
int i=0;
while (i <= 10)
{
    // do something
    ++i
}
```

The choice between them is usually just about readability, as either can easily be made to perform as the other.

On top of that, a couple of useful keywords to know for use in loops are:

- `continue` — stop this iteration of the loop & start the next one
- `break` — exit the loop

So however you program your loop, you could always include a check like:

```
    // do something (inside the loop)...
    if ( temp <= -274 )
    {
        break;
    }
```

In your case, you probably want to include both a counter (like the for loop iterator) and an end-condition, because it would be useful to report on these, and/or raise errors if there are less than 28 or more than 31 samples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sentinel in the `for` loop, just logically `&&` it to the condition:

```
for (x = 0 ; x < 31 && temp != 500; ++x)
```

Comment: That way he will not be able to get data for all 31 days

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not giving away too much, but to make better use of the fact that a sentinel value can be used, ...

You can make a 32-element array and fill the final 5 positions with your sentinel, -500. Then your processing loop can always terminate on that value and you no longer need to check the bounds of the loop.

```
int array[32];
int i;
array[27]=array[28]=array[29]=array[30]=array[31]=-500;

// read 28,29,30 or 31 values.

for (i=0; array[i] != -500; i++) {
    // process temp
}
```